Unity texture changing when coming close with a camera
I added and installed shader graph and followd a tutorial for having the terain curve,
Then after adding it to all objects in the terain i realised that the textures are weard it looks buggy this was not the problem befour.
I am using unity 2022.3.35f1. and macos hekintosh with 14900kf and rx5700XT)
Images:
Inspector settings
Sheader graph
How the game looks
I tryed using solid colors and turnig off lights in preview none of those fixed it, i tryed mesing with inpector and quality settings but that can be the solution and i just dident fixz it corectly
